# Get result outside subscribe in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a component's method, but it has some unexpected behavior:

```
private fetchExternalStyleSheet(outerHTML: string): string[] {
  let externalStyleSheetText: string;
  let match: RegExpExecArray;

  const matchedHrefs = [];
  while (match = this.hrefReg.exec(outerHTML)) {
    matchedHrefs.push(match[1]);
  }
  const requestedUrl = this.url + matchedHrefs[0];
  this._ApiService.makeRequest(requestedUrl, ActionType.content)
    .subscribe((response: any) => {
      externalStyleSheetText = response.content;
      console.log('inside subscribe', externalStyleSheetText); // => expected content
  });
  console.log('outside subscribe', externalStyleSheetText); // => undefined

  return this.parseStyleSheetText(externalStyleSheetText);
}
```

inside `.subscribe` method `externalStyleSheetText` binding has expected value, while outside it gives me undefined. I suppose it related with async behavior of subscribe method. I reviewed some related issues but still it is unsolved, because of the fact that everybody suggests make request via `subscribe` in `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook and it means that we get request result before component initialization. But in my case I have to make it outside `ngOnInit`, so I get `undefined`

Comment: May I ask why you need this, since what you described it's proper and expected behavior of Observable?

Comment: I should parse external style sheet content to find @media queries, so I have to retrieve  style sheet  text first

Comment: I have to pass `externalStyleSheetText` to `parseStyleSheetText` method

Comment: Then Invoke the method inside Subscribe callback

Comment: @a_zatula, as it was said, use parseStyleSheetText method just inside subscribe and if needed then emit this to parent component.

Comment: You are working with async Programming you need to change your approach. Kindly Have a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @andrey.shedko, well how to emit result of  `parseStyleSheetText` ?

Comment: @a_zatula have you taken a look at my answer? Does it help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve it, I suppose you have to make `fetchExternalStyleSheet` return an observable, and subscribe to it from the outside call. So `fetchExternalStyleSheet` will look something like this:

```
private fetchExternalStyleSheet(outerHTML: string): Observable<string[]> {
    let externalStyleSheetText: string;
    let match: RegExpExecArray;

    const matchedHrefs = [];
    while (match = this.hrefReg.exec(outerHTML)) {
      matchedHrefs.push(match[1]);
    }
    const requestedUrl = this.url + matchedHrefs[0];
    return this._ApiService.makeRequest(requestedUrl, ActionType.content)
      .pipe(map((response: any) => {
        externalStyleSheetText = response.content;
        return this.parseStyleSheetText(externalStyleSheetText);
      }));
  }
```

and in the call, you subscribe to the result, like this:

```
callerMethod() {
    this.fetchExternalStyleSheet('<h1>Test</h1>').subscribe(response => {
      this.parsedStylesheet = response;
    })
  }
```

I made a stackblitz, where clicking a button calls `callerMethod`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpogff